# Using promise callbacks for multiple events without global variables

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise wrapped in a function. I will call this function multiple times using different input parameters. Each time the promise resolves I push the resolved value into a storage array.

When all my called promises have resolved I will then use this storage array in other functions.

If there any clean way to set this up without using "global-ish" variables?

The code below is the only way I can think of to make this work:

```
// Set global-ish variables that can be referenced from multiple functions
var storageArray = [];
var numberOfPromiseCalls = 10;
var promiseCallsCount = 0;

// Setup promise wrapper
function promiseWrapper(inputParams){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // awesome stuff at work here using inputParams
    resolve(desiredOutput);
  }
})

// call promise 10 times
for(i=0;i<numberOfPromiseCalls;i++){

  // actual promise call
  promiseWrapper(inputParams[i]).then(function (desiredOutput) {

    // push resolve to storage array
    storageArray.push(desiredOutput);

    // test if this resolve is the "last" resolve of all the promises we called
    promiseCallsCount++;
    if(promiseCallsCount == numberOfPromiseCalls){

      // ************************
      // call a function that can work with the final storageArray
      // ************************

    }
  })
}
```

I mean, the code above works, but man it feels ugly. There's a lot of ambiguity going on and variable hierarchy's you have to keep track of. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: how are you getting resolve scope here - `storageArray.push(resolve);` ??

Comment: @McRist Sorry my mistake. Translating into pseudo code and I didn't catch that. It's edited now.

Comment: "*I have a promise which I will call multiple times*" - a promise cannot be called, it's a result value. And it cannot resolve multiple times. Do you mean that you have a function that returns a promise?

Comment: @Bergi yes that is what I meant, I'll edit the question to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you using of `Promise.all` with passing an array of your promises. Invoking `then` will let you to handle all response when all of the promises are resolved.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
for (i=0;i<numberOfPromiseCalls;i++){
  storageArray.push(promiseWrapper(inputParams[i]));
}

Promise.all(storageArray).then(responses => {
  // responses is an array of all promises responses
});
```